# Docker compose- Spring boot service not connecting to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

### ---For Docker desktop on windows (on linux containers)---
Postman Error -"message": "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)".

Docker compose log-  productservice    | com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

```
Spring properties -------
spring.data.mongodb.database=product
#spring.data.mongodb.username=root
#spring.data.mongodb.password=root
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.host=api-database
#spring.data.mongodb.host=host.docker.internal

Dockerfile ---------
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
COPY ./target/ProductService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/ProductService/
WORKDIR /usr/src/ProductService
EXPOSE 8105
CMD ["java", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://api-database:27017/api-database","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","./ProductService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

Docker-compose.yml -----
version: '3'
services:
product-server:
container_name: productservice
image: productservice
 expose:
 - 8105
 ports:
  - 8105:8105
 links:
 - api-database
                  
depends_on:
 - api-database
   
networks: 
 - backend

api-database:
 image:mongo
container_name: api-database
 restart: always
 hostname: api-database
networks:  - backend

networks:
backend:
driver: "bridge"
```

Comment: Please edit the post to fix the formatting, especially of the YAML file (whitespace matters).  Is there more of the error that says what it's failing to connect to?  If you run `docker-compose up -d`, wait 30-60 seconds, and try again, does it start up successfully?

Comment: Thanks David for reply. Both services starts successfully. Running with docker-compose up -d gives--                                                                                                       Starting api-database ... done
Recreating productservice ... done